# jQuery: On click ajax, get the clicked object in done/fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Simple ajax query, but being triggered for every item of a class using the `.click()` event.  When it gets to the `.done()` I cannot figure out how to look up the element which was clicked so I can properly remove the `m_action` class.

Below is the code.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I've been searching with Chrome and Firefox web tools without luck, and can't find a duplicate question here on Stack.

In short: **using the code below, how do I properly remove the `m_action` class of the clicked element on a successful jQuery ajax return?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("div#normal .m_action").click(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "./action.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: this.id }
        }).done(function(result) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("m_action");
            jQuery(this).html(result);
        }).fail(function(result) {
            alert("There was an error.")
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just store a reference to it so that it is available anywhere in that scope:

```
jQuery("div#normal .m_action").click(function() {

    var elem = this; // <-- right here

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { action: this.id }
    }).done(function(result) {
        jQuery(elem).removeClass("m_action"); // <-- elem is still available
        jQuery(elem).html(result); // <--
    }).fail(function(result) {
        alert("There was an error.")
    });
});
```

Just a note for the future, your problem doesn't have to do with jQuery. This is just a simple use of variables within a scope. The `this` pointer changes within the done function, so you just needed to cache the reference.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I realize it's a scoping issue, but it seems to be query-specific.  Why does passing `action: this.id` work, but referencing `this` in the `.done()` function not?  jQuery/Javascript's "functions are data" concept is still a little confusing to this jQuery newbie (who started programming in Java).

Comment: @Bing You're creating an object in the `click` function's scope and passing it to the `ajax` function. Look at it like this and it makes a lot more sense: http://jsbin.com/giyan/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery(".m_action").click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "./action.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: this.id }
        }).done(function(result) {
            self.removeClass("m_action");
            self.html(result);
        }).fail(function(result) {
            alert("There was an error.")
        });
    })

});
</script>
```